# How to type function parameter so that only keys of another target are allowed?

Tags: typescript

I'm looking to make a `tween` function in typescript that accepts a target instance, and a plain object with `{key: newValue}`. A **subset** of keys that are in the target must be allowed.

How can I type this correctly without getting `An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'number'.ts(1023)`

The tween function:

```js
export function tween<T>(
  target: T,
  properties: { [key: keyof T]: number },
) {
  // ...
}
```

Example usage:

```js
class A {
  b = 3;
}
tween(new A(), {b: 5});
```

Comment: Must it be *all* keys as in `Record<keyof T, number>`?  Or just *some* keys as in `Partial<Record<keyof T, number>>`?

Comment: Short answer is: `keyof T` is not a valid index signature; instead you want [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) which uses a similar syntax but is not the same.  `{[key: keyof T]: number}` bad, `{[K in keyof T]: number}` good.

Comment: Thanks, that pointed me in the right direction. For the record, it had to be _some_ keys.

Comment: Since this has been closed, I'll have to post the answer here: `properties: { [K in keyof T]?: number }`